# C++ identical method signature but different return type

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have seen the following code:

```
template <class T>
class Type {
    public:
        Type() {}
        T& operator=(const T& rhs) {value() = rhs; return value();}
        T& value() {return m_value;}
        T value() const {return m_value;}
    private:
        T m_value;
};
```

Why does the compiler not complain about

```
    T& value() {return m_value;}
    T value() const {return m_value;}
```

and how to know which one is invoked?

Comment: Do not ignore keywords when determining whether or not two function signatures are "identical"!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two functions are actually not the same. Only the second function is declared as a `const` member function. If the object that the member is called from is `const`, the latter option is used. If the object is non-`const`, the first option is used.

Example:

```
void any_func(const Type *t)
{
    something = t->value(); //second `const` version used
}

void any_func2(Type *t)
{
    something = t->value(); //first non-`const` version used
}
```

If both functions were declared non-`const` or both were declared `const`, the compiler *would* (should, anyway) complain.

Answer (score 7):

> Why does the compiler not complain about

Because the `const` counts for a different function signature. Your assumption the *function signatures are identical* is wrong.
The function marked as `const` will be invoked for any `const` instance or reference of `Type<T>`.

> and how to know which one is invoked?

Put a `cout` statement in the functions and test the following cases:

```
template <class T>
class Type {
    public:
        Type() {}
        T& operator=(const T& rhs) {value() = rhs; return value();}
        T& value() { 
            std::cout << "non const version" << std endl;
            return m_value;
        }
        T value() const { 
            std::cout << "const version" << std endl;
            return m_value;
        }
    private:
        T m_value;
};
```

---

```
int main() {
    Type<int> t;
    t.value();

    Type<int> rt = t;
    rt.value();

    Type<int>* pt = &t;
    pt->value();

    const Type<int> ct;
    ct.value();

    const Type<int>& crt = t;
    crt.value();

    const Type<int>* pct = &t;
    pct->value();
}
```

Your assignment operator will call the non const version.

---

The const version should better look like

```
const T& value() const { 
     std::cout << "const version" << std endl;
     return m_value;
}
```

because you can't always rely on RVO (return value optimization), and extra copies might be taken (especially for older compiler implementations).

---

Also note the assignment operator should return a reference to the current instance:

```
 Type& operator=(const T& rhs) {value() = rhs; return *this;}
```

Answer (score 5):

A couple of words on functions resolution priority. Compiler distinguishes between const/non const functions on following way:

If a class has only const function with given name and argument list, it will be called for constant and non-constant objects alike. After calling this function, object will 'assume' constness (even if it was not const), meaning that the function can only call other const functions.

If a class has only non-const function, it will be called for non-const objects. Attempt to call this function for const objects  will lead to compilation error.

If a class has both functions available, const version will be used for const objects, non-const version will be used for non-const objects.

Thanks to @owacoder for pointing my attention to initial mixup in the description.

Comment: I think the logic in the second paragraph is backwards. Non-`const` functions **can't** be called for `const` objects.

Comment: @owacoder, my bad. You are correct, I misread your comment and mistyped my answer. Will edit it.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. @jaggedSpire is correct, I was skimming and not reading carefully. Mea culpa.